# openmeetings error : cannot validate with the turn server

Tags: coturn, openmeetings

I cannot make any video chats on openmeetings. I can see myself but I cannot see the other person and same is happening at the other end. I am getting an error on the client side (browser)

> WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more
> details

I made the configurations as suggested here - https://markmail.org/message/3dgy62lj3m74mogy

- coturn server with `use-auth-secret` and `static-auth-secret`

In the coturn server, I am getting entries that the user validation is failed.

Can somebody guide on this?

FYI I am using 6.3.0 version. And Deploying this on AWS ECS - separate containers for Openmeetings, Kurento and Coturn. I am using the om docker image - `apache/openmeetings:min-6.3.0`

Comment: Have you specified these params: https://github.com/openmeetings/openmeetings-docker/#useful-parameters ?

Comment: Yes. I did specify TURN_URL, TURN_PASS (secret). For TURN_USER I tried with no value as well as some 'not_to_be_used' sample value.

Comment: these values should correspond the coturn config. Try `cat /etc/turnserver.conf|grep -v '^#'|grep -v -e '^$'` and check `static-auth-secret` matches `TURN_PASS` :)

Comment: Yes it matches. I removed my custom coturn server and used the public available (open relay). Also I moved my kurento to EC2. Its working now.

Comment: @MaximSolodovnik - I see kurento is opening ports when turn server is used. Why does kurento need additional ports? Any ideas? My assumption is that only the turn server needs to relay the traffic and it does with the help of ports.

Comment: AFAIK TURN server acts as server-in-the-middle in case there is no way to make IP addresses of both parties available to each other. thus streams are being send via TURN server this will require some additional ports